# Ubuntu and UPower doesn't recognise charge state correctly

Tags: 16.04, power-management, asus, battery

I have an Asus UX330CA.

Brand new computer (no I haven't tripped over the power cord.)

When the battery is not full, and it is plugged in, it responds correctly. (Battery icon in the top left, with a lightning bolt in it, details say "charging" and ac power connected.)

When you remove the AC adaptor, it changes and says "discharging" ac power disconnected.

When it charges up to appx 98-100% it switches from the battery with the lightning bolt, to just the battery, and then in the details states that it is discharging. It still has AC power connected in the details and physically, but the battery is no longer charging, not in a charged state, but claims to be discharging. The icon will then continue to say 99 or 100%.

I did not test this on Windows that the computer came with. I'm running Ubunutu 16.04.3 Fresh install, haven't played around with anything.

I did update the bios as some other pages suggested.

I tried installing 17.04, but then the keyboard failed and I reinstalled 16.04.3

I have included the outputs of upower --monitor-detail

<<--- This is where I unplugged the adaptor --->>

```
Monitoring activity from the power daemon. Press Ctrl+C to cancel.

[12:55:35.241]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 11 Aug 2017 12:55:35 PM ADT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              51.697 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         52.644 Wh
    energy-full-design:  54.054 Wh
    energy-rate:         6.491 W
    voltage:             11.55 V
    time to empty:       8.0 hours
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            97.3915%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1502466935  6.491   discharging
    1502466932  5.162   discharging

[12:55:32.263]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 11 Aug 2017 12:55:32 PM ADT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              no
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'



<<--- Plugged it back in here --->>

[12:55:35.242]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/line_power_AC0
  native-path:          AC0
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 11 Aug 2017 12:55:35 PM ADT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          no
  has statistics:       no
  line-power
    warning-level:       none
    online:              yes
    icon-name:          'ac-adapter-symbolic'


[12:55:35.242]  daemon changed:
  daemon-version:  0.99.4
  on-battery:      no
  lid-is-closed:   no
  lid-is-present:  yes
  critical-action: HybridSleep

[12:57:35.251]  device changed:     /org/freedesktop/UPower/devices/battery_BAT0
  native-path:          BAT0
  vendor:               ASUSTeK
  model:                ASUS Battery
  power supply:         yes
  updated:              Fri 11 Aug 2017 12:57:35 PM ADT (0 seconds ago)
  has history:          yes
  has statistics:       yes
  battery
    present:             yes
    rechargeable:        yes
    state:               discharging
    warning-level:       none
    energy:              51.674 Wh
    energy-empty:        0 Wh
    energy-full:         52.644 Wh
    energy-full-design:  54.054 Wh
    energy-rate:         0.0276394 W
    voltage:             11.55 V
    percentage:          98%
    capacity:            97.3915%
    technology:          lithium-ion
    icon-name:          'battery-full-symbolic'
  History (rate):
    1502467055  0.028   discharging
```

I should add that I did unplug the adapter overnight and ran the battery down to 1% before giving it a full charge and then leaving it overnight again before doing this.

Seems to be identical to this one as well:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385052/asus-zenbook-battery-is-never-fully-charged/385360#385360

Comment: Have you fully updated the OS already?

Comment: I'm running the 16.04.3 LTS.

I've run all the updates available without going to 17.04 that one locked up the keyboard, and looked to exhibit the same symptoms.

Comment: Further investigation, and it seems this is a common problem on the Asus UX330CA. I've found two other individuals with the same situation.

Additional note: over the period of about 5 days, the laptop, while plugged in an charging, will slowly discharge down from 100 to 95%, at 95% it will then recognise a charge state and charge it back up to 100. Then it repeats the process.

Any thoughts from anyone? If this is a designed feature in order to help the battery, should it not show the "charge icon" or atleast a "charged icon" when its completing this process?

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same issue with Asus Zenbook UX430UQ with Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS 64 bit. My motherboard bios version was 300 released on 13/July/2017. Downgraded to older 201 firmware released on 10/Feb/2017. Now battery notification and charging beautifully. Hope it helps you.